# UML cloud: edit models, store and generate code in the cloud?

Tags: cloud, uml

I'm looking for a lightweight UML modeler in the cloud. Some kind of google-drive for uml-compliant modelling. My objective is to introduce UML in my small team with the minimum of constraints. My needs are:

- Edit the models anywhere without installation (my team won't put any effort into another IDE installation)
- UML-compliant modelling. I must provide validated and documented architecture models
- Java code generator.
- Reliable service for daily work

Comment: If you generate code with a web/cloud service. How do you plan to get it into your IDE? Or do you want a whole Java IDE with UML in the cloud? (which does not exists, yet, afaik).

Comment: We presently use Eclipse coupled with Github repositories. We plan to use online IDEs in the coming months, such as codenvy. So I guess cloud-based generators could push in online repositories, then I pull in the online IDE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GenMyModel can really help you. This cloud-based tool is described at [UML cloud](http://www.genmymodel.com/).

It creates models in your web-browser and they are stored in the cloud. There's nothing to download or install. The generated code can be pushed to your Github repositories.

I use it in my team and I'd say the application is reliable. Only class diagrams and use case diagrams are available right now; you don't have all the diagrams provided by old-fashioned UML modelers. But it's online!

Comment: Perfect, this tool is impressive!

Comment: Thanks Georges! The sequence diagrams would be a great improvement, especially for unit test generation. By the way that's a relief to see that my development projects will fully be designed, coded and deployed in the cloud. My project manager gonna be happy :)

Comment: Real-time collaborative modeling is now available in GenMyModel. It lets you work with your mates on the same UML model while keeping the UML compliance